# EJb, direct ServerSocket or any other implementation

Tags: java, c#, android, ejb, serversocket

I am working on a Chatting Website project which will provide similar features as was  like yahoo messenger with chat rooms...
Where multiple clients will connect to the central server and chatting(communication) and file sharing(if possible) will take place.
Now i did a bit of research and i came out with the following choices:

For the client i will use either Winforms or WPF with c#

And for server I am confused between,

Direct Servesocket based application to be deployed on a VPN or a dedicated server,

or EJB based something, 
Or any other technology as you may suggest to be suitable for this.

kindly keep somethings in mind:
1. It should be scalable enough to be able to sustain 100 - 1000 to 1,00,000 clients
2. Server should also serve android app as client end. 
3. Deployment details also requested

Comment: I suggest you to have a look at singalR from microsoft. Not sure whether it will serve android app or not.

Comment: I dont want chat on website, we will have special client end software for desktop nd android for mobile... will singalR work?

Comment: singalR is designed for Web app but you can still use for windows apps, here is the demo http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/804770/Implementing-SignalR-in-Desktop-Applications

Comment: Will it be able to connect to android apps